# I am using p5.js and I am getting the error: "loadAnimation is not defined and createSprite not defined." (same happening in VSCode)

Tags: javascript, p5.js

```
    var bg, sleep, brush, gym, eat, drink, move, astronaut;

function preload() 
{
  bg = loadImage("images/iss.png");
  sleep = loadAnimation("images/sleep.png");
  brush = loadAnimation("images/brush.png");
  gym = loadAnimation("images/gym1.png","images/gym1.png","images/gym2.png","images/gym12.png");
  eat = loadAnimation("images/eat1.png", "images/eat2.png");
  drink = loadAnimation("images/drink1.png", "images/drink2.");
  move = loadAnimation("images/move.png", "images/move1.png");
}

function setup()
{
  createCanvas(400, 400); 

  astronaut = createSprite(300, 200);
  astronaut.addAnimation("sleeping", sleep);
  astronaut.scale = 0.3;
}

function draw() 
{
  background(bg);

  drawSprites();
}
```

I have to tried to retype it and checked the files I am loading. It still doesnt seem to be working or doing anything.

link to file: https://editor.p5js.org/tyagihersh/sketches/Vw6exQaUr

[image]

Comment: could share the link of your p5.js application?

Comment: @0brine here https://editor.p5js.org/tyagihersh/sketches/Vw6exQaUr

Comment: what do you expect loadAnimation() and createSprite() to do?
Looks like you are missing an library

Comment: Uhh idk i thought i found the missin library but no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your index.html to

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.1.9/p5.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.1.9/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
    <script src="p5.play.js"></script>
    <script src="p5.dom.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

the result should be this
[image]

for more infos look at the example project from p5
https://editor.p5js.org/ebenjmuse/sketches/BJ4fQ9WxG

Comment: i tried this but it didnt work should i try copying their whole index.htm?

Comment: i tried but now its showing me this error: "Event {isTrusted: true, constructor: Object}"

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.1.9/p5.js"></script>
    <script src="p5.play.js"></script>
    <script src="p5.dom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.1.9/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
 This is my index @0brine

Comment: Yes, now add those 2 lines

Comment: @TAGBLACK look at the changes made to this post